# Set up Commercial SSL Certificate for SharePoint 2013 Web Application and Site Collections Hosted on Azure

Tags: sharepoint, azure, ssl, https

We have not been able to Set up Commercial SSL Certificate for SharePoint 2013 Web Application and Site Collections Hosted on Azure after so many attempts.

Our SharePoint 2013 web application and site collections are set up on Azure and we have to use the http://mycompanyname.cloudapp.net domain.

When we try to down the trial VeriSign SSL Certificate, we could not use http://mycompany.cloudapp.net domain so we had to use www.mycompany.com domain to download the Trial SSL Certificate.

As a result, the SSL Certificates were not configured successfully.

Please could you guide me how to Set up Commercial SSL Certificate for SharePoint 2013 Web Application and Site Collections Hosted on Azure?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind advice.

Comment: It seems like your issue is with *"VeriSign SSL Certificate"*, so you should probably follow up with Verisign. They will be more than happy to talk with you. As a matter of fact, you Inbox will probably be subject to an endless stream of chatter: marketing emails and phishing attempts. The phishing attempts will be humorous: they will tell you someone (maybe you) made an account change and they need you to log in and approve it. Here, "approve it" means charge your credit card.

Comment: Hi JWW, Thank you very much for your advice. To my understanding, .cloudapp.net domain belongs to Microsoft so we cannot purchase an SSL for .cloudapp.net. It is critical for us to set up SSL and I have seen others doing it successfully but I have not found a document with instructions for this process. If you happen to know, please kindly give me a pointer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy a custom domain that matches the one you registered for your certificate.  Depending on how you have deployed your farm you may need to deploy the SSL certificate in a range of locations.  I'd start by following this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you very much for the link. I will give it a go. I have a couple of questions 1. How to deploy a custom domain for the web application 2. Will the custom domain work for the site collections For example: web application https://mycompanyname.com, site collection 1 https://mycompanyname.com/sites/department1, site collection 2 https://mycompanyname.com/sites/department2